# How can I print nulls when converting a dataframe to json in Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that I read from a csv.

```
CSV:
name,age,pets
Alice,23,dog
Bob,30,dog
Charlie,35,

Reading this into a DataFrame called myData:
+-------+---+----+
|   name|age|pets|
+-------+---+----+
|  Alice| 23| dog|
|    Bob| 30| dog|
|Charlie| 35|null|
+-------+---+----+
```

Now, I want to convert each row of this dataframe to a json using `myData.toJSON`. What I get are the following jsons.

```
{"name":"Alice","age":"23","pets":"dog"}
{"name":"Bob","age":"30","pets":"dog"}
{"name":"Charlie","age":"35"}
```

I would like the 3rd row's json to include the null value. Ex.

```
{"name":"Charlie","age":"35", "pets":null}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be possible. I debugged through the code and saw that Spark's `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JacksonGenerator` class has the following implementation

```
  private def writeFields(
    row: InternalRow, schema: StructType, fieldWriters: 
    Seq[ValueWriter]): Unit = {
    var i = 0
    while (i < row.numFields) {
      val field = schema(i)
      if (!row.isNullAt(i)) {
        gen.writeFieldName(field.name)
        fieldWriters(i).apply(row, i)
      }
      i += 1
    }
  }
```

This seems to be skipping a column if it is null. I am not quite sure why this is the default behavior but is there a way to print null values in json using Spark's `toJSON`?

I am using **Spark 2.1.0**

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 5):

To print the null values in JSON using Spark's `toJSON` method, you can use following code:

```
myData.na.fill("null").toJSON
```

It will give you expected result:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|value                                      |
+-------------------------------------------+
|{"name":"Alice","age":"23","pets":"dog"}   |
|{"name":"Bob","age":"30","pets":"dog"}     |
|{"name":"Charlie","age":"35","pets":"null"}|
+-------------------------------------------+
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I don't want to use na.fill because that puts double-quotes around null. That's not the same as setting the value to null.

Comment: @Rahul You can use `df.na.fill(null.asInstanceOf[String])` and you will get `"pets":""`

Comment: @himanshuIIITian, your approach will also not work for data types other than Strings. I have upvoted your answer but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @philantrovert, I don't need an empty string. I need a null. Also if the data type of the column is, say, Int, I'll get a 0 instead of null.

Answer (score 4):

I have modified JacksonGenerator.writeFields function and included in my project.
Below are the steps-

1) Create package 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json' inside 'src/main/scala/'

2) Copy JacksonGenerator class

3) Create JacksonGenerator.scala class in '' package and paste the copied code

4) modify writeFields function

```
private def writeFields(row: InternalRow, schema: StructType, fieldWriters:Seq[ValueWriter]): Unit = {
var i = 0
while (i < row.numFields) {
  val field = schema(i)
  if (!row.isNullAt(i)) {
    gen.writeFieldName(field.name)
    fieldWriters(i).apply(row, i)
  }
  else{
    gen.writeNullField(field.name)
  }
  i += 1
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

tested with Spark 3.0.0:

When creating your spark session, set `spark.sql.jsonGenerator.ignoreNullFields` to false.

The `toJSON` function internally uses `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JacksonGenerator`, which in turn takes `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JSONOptions` for configuration.
The latter includes an option `ignoreNullFields`.
However, `toJSON` uses the defaults, which in the case of this particular option is taken from the sql config given above.

An example with the configuration set to false:

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("a", StringType), StructField("b", StringType)))
val rows = Seq(Row("a", null), Row(null, "b"))
val frame = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rows), schema)
println(frame.toJSON.collect().mkString("\n"))
```

produces

```
{"a":"a","b":null}
{"a":null,"b":"b"}
```

Comment: It worked, but an example of how to change the config would be really useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject

def convertRowToJSON(row: Row): String = {
    val m = row.getValuesMap(row.schema.fieldNames).filter(_._2 != null)
    JSONObject(m).toString()
  }
```

Comment: Add context around your answer for future learning purpose and downvote prevention. (From Review).