# Database DataFrame Null values not coming to Json File

Tags: java, json, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a database containing null values in some columns and I am converting the dataframe formed from the database to Json file. The problem here is that I am not getting the null columns. Here is the code as well as the output:

```
            dataFrame.show();
            dataFrame.na().fill("null").coalesce(1)
            .write()
            .mode("append")
            .format("Json")
            .option("nullValue", "")
            .save("D:\\XML File Testing\\"+"JsonParty1");
```

The dataframe.show() gives the following output:

[![Dataframe as processed by the spark][1]][1]

```
             [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxAQC.png
```

Here is how it is being saved in the File (I am pasting just 1 column just to show you the example):

```
           {"EMPNO":7839,"ENAME":"KING","JOB":"PRESIDENT","HIREDATE":"1981-11-17T00:00:00.000+05:30","SAL":5000.00,"DEPTNO":10}
```

As you can see my "MGR" and "comm" column is missing because it is showing null in the dataframe. Surprisingly this thing works when the dataframe is formed from a file(Structured, example:delimited txt file) containing empty values(the spark dataframe takes it as null). Tried various approaches but still failed to get the null columns in the Json file. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I print nulls when converting a dataframe to json in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45626631/how-can-i-print-nulls-when-converting-a-dataframe-to-json-in-spark)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already looked that article and as I said that na().fill("") works when the dataframe is made from a structured file but when the dataframe is made from a DB then this same thing doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
dataFrame.withColumn("json", to_json(struct(dataFrame.columns.map(col):_*)
    .select("json").write.mode("append").text("D:\\XML File Testing\\"+"JsonParty1")
```

Comment: What is the col used in the map as parameter. Its giving me error as variable not resolved. Can you give some more information?

Comment: Also its saying that there exists no map() for columns().

Comment: This code is in Scala. If you need in Java you can use Intellij to convert it to Java.

Comment: Can I get the java code for compilation as I wouldn't be able to install intellij in my workplace.

Comment: I am not familiar with Java API but here idea is to create `struct` column with all columns and convert that to json. And, finally select json column and save it as text.

Comment: What I am confused is about when a structured File(for ex# CSV or TXT)dataframe is formed then the null values come to the Json file with the above code but when Database dataframe is formed then the above code doesn't work. How is this possible?

Comment: No the code that I added(in the question). Any idea on why that is happening?